# Get value form wordpress database

Tags: database

I'm sorry if this ambiguous but I'll try my best

I have the following php code from a WordPress Plugin

`$url = 'http://mydomain.com/'.$ListingID.'/';`

I need to define a value for `$ListingID`

The value will come from the wordpress database and is found in the table called 
wp_fsrep_listings

the name of the column in the table is 
listing_id

and the value is related to a listing page that is similar to a normal wp post page.

Therefore is presume I need to define the "value" in this manner

`$ListingID = "value"`

How do I define the "value"?

Thank You

Comment: So you have a post ID and you need to get the associated listing ID, but you haven't given us all the needed column names in your table. Can you provide the full schema?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) in WordPress for you to be able to read/write DB.

To get variable from table, use [$wpdb->get_var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable) function. This way:

```
//set current page ID or define ID in another way - depends on your code
$my_page_id = get_the_ID(); 
global $wpdb;
$ListingID = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT listing_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."fsrep_listings WHERE ID = " . $my_page_id );
echo "<p>Listing id is {$ListingID}</p>";
```

In the code i presume, that the table has ID column keeping page/post/custom_post_type ID value to match with page/post_custom_post_type.

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work. There wasn't an error the URL just displayed as `http://mydomain.com//`

Comment: This answer assumes a post ID is stored in an ID column, since you never mentioned how the listing ID mapped to the post ID, if any of those assumptions fail then the code will not work as is